# Generating a random number in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, frameworks, random

In my cakephp controller, I want to have a variable that stores a random number that any function can access. The random number variable will indicate a certain array that multiple functions will use. I've tried a bunch of variations of the rand() function, most recently:

```
$rand = rand(1, 4);
```

outside of the controller class and inside the controller class. Can anyone help? Much appreciated?

Andrew

Answer (score 2):

Add something like this to your controller:

```
function beforeFilter() {
  $this->myRandomNumber = rand(1,4);
}
```

Now you can use `$this->myRandomNumber` from everywhere within the controller. It will stay the same during the request.

Answer (score 0):

Is this number changing constantly?  If not, why not set a random variable in your config file.

If yes, use rand and store it....or if you want letters too, use something like md5(time + salt)

Answer (score 0):

Does the random generator function has to do anything with databases? If no, I would add the function to bootstrap.php at config folder

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use [`array_rand`](http://php.net/array_rand) if the random number would change depending on the size of an array.

You can put the variable in a config file if the random number should be constant within the same request, or make a model/plugin to store a method that does this precise line:

```
return array_rand($my_array);
```